# How can I keep my Twitter Bot awake with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, server, bots

My main purpose is creating a twitter bot. Which is basically going to retweet tweets from certain accounts. Everything works properly except keeping the bot awake. In order to keep to bot awake, I need to leave my laptop and console open. How can I deploy an App that will do this for me? I want to put the server to work for all this. I tried with Heroku but it gives timeout as expected cause request is should be open to keep my method going.

Thanks in advance...

my method:

```
    def self.start_bot
    @client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = ENV["CONSUMER_KEY"]
      config.consumer_secret     = ENV["CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY"]
      config.access_token        = ENV["ACCESS_TOKEN"]
      config.access_token_secret = ENV["ACCESS_SECRET_TOKEN"]
    end

    while true do
      begin
        @client.search("from:ExampleAccount1 OR from:ExampleAccount1 OR from:ExampleAccount1
min_faves:250 -rt", result_type: "recent").take(5).collect do |tweet|
            begin
              @client.fav(tweet)
              @client.retweet(tweet)
              sleep(2)
            rescue
              puts "Already retweeted."
              sleep(3)
            end
        end
        puts "one round completed."
        sleep(120)
      rescue
        puts "Something Happened"
        sleep(240)
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for your requirement you can use [#clockwork_gem](https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork)

You need to do the following:

- Firstly install the clockwork gem.

In your lib folder create a lib/clock.rb

```
### Example :-
require 'clockwork'
require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'

module Clockwork

  handler do |job|
    puts "Running #{job}"
  end

  every(1.day, 'Creating Cycle', :at => '12:00') {YourClass_name.start_bot}
end
```

- Create a procfile
  To your `Procfile` use like this

  ```
  worker: bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb
  ```

it will start the server every time after Heroku push/web server restart.

Or you can run using console from your computer like this but in this case, you need to run every time after web server restarting

```
heroku run bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb
```

and from Heroku open console and type

```
bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: thank you so much for the effort. your solution is exactly what I need :) I had to otherwise before solution. I mean I found an Add-on for heroku and it's called "Heroku Scheduler". It's basically same thing with your solution. Thank you!